# Which mode to use for ECMAScript 6?

Tags: major-mode, syntax-highlighting

Is there a mode out there that has syntax higlighting (and possibly more, but this is the least I want) for a more recent ecmascript? I'm especially interested in one that has support for template strings and generator functions.

This should render properly:

```
co(function*(){
   var a = yield request(`some.domain/${variable}`)
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[js2-mode](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode) supports all of this. It is available on GNU ELPA and MELPA for easy access.

Comment: Thanks! I was using `js3-mode` and `js-mode` and somehow thought js3 is a fork of js2.